# Laurent series for $f (z)=\frac {\sin (2 \pi z)}{z (z^2 + 1)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

How Can find the Laurent series for this function valid for $0 <|z-i|<2$ $$f (z)=\frac {\sin (2 \pi z)}{z (z^2 +1)}$$

Let $g (z) = \sin (\pi z)$

$$\sin (\pi z ) = \sin( 2 \pi  (z - i)) \cos (2 \pi i) + \cos (2 \pi  (z-i)) \sin (2 \pi i )$$

And Let $h (z)= \frac {1}{z^2 + 1}$

$$\frac {1}{z (z^2 + 1)}= \frac {1}{i (1 -(-(z-i))}[\frac {1/2i}{z-i} +\frac {-1/2i}{2i (1-(-\frac {z-i}{2i}))}]$$

So it's easy to find expansion for $g (z)$ and $h (z)$ and then multiply the two expansions

We notice that $ f $ has simple pole at $z = i$ So, we can get the principal part easily Or using this 
$$2 \pi i a_1 = \int_{|z-i|=1} f (z) dz$$

Is there a trick to find the Laurent series quickly ?

This question was in my exam .I Calculated the principal part , but I didn't have enough time to calculate the exact form for the analytic part .

Thank you

Comment: No, there is none, and the computations are quite tedious. Giving this an an exam subject is not very smart on the part of your professor (it would make for a good homework exercise, though). The core is to compute the Taylor series of $\dfrac {\sin 2\pi z} {z (z + \Bbb i)}$ at $\Bbb i$, which is time-consuming and, worse, does not have a closed form. You do this by multiplying the Taylor series of the three factors, and you can see how ugly this is.

Comment: I highly doubt there is a nice general form. Look at this https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin+(2+%5Cpi+z)%7D%7Bz+(z%5E2+%2B1)%7D+around+z+%3Di

Comment: Detalized version. Can be reduced on the exam...

Answer (score 5):

First we obtain

$$\dfrac{1}{z(z+i)}=\dfrac{i}{z+i}-\dfrac{i}{z}=\dfrac{1}{2\left(1+\dfrac{z-i}{2i}\right)}-\dfrac{1}{\left(1+\dfrac{z-i}{i}\right)}={\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\left\{\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{(2i)^k}-\dfrac{1}{i^k}\right\}\cdot(z-i)^k}.$$

The Taylor series converges for $\vert z-i\vert\lt1$. Next we obtain

$$\sin(2\pi z)=\sin\{2\pi(z-i)+2\pi i\}=
{\sin\{2\pi(z-i)\}\cos(2\pi i)+\cos\{2\pi(z-i)\}\sin(2\pi i)}=
{\cos(2\pi i)\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\dfrac{\{2\pi (z-i)\}^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}+\sin(2\pi i)\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\dfrac{\{2\pi (z-i)\}^{2k}}{(2k)!}}=
{\cos(2\pi i)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sin\dfrac{k\pi}{2}\cdot\dfrac{\{2\pi (z-i)\}^{k}}{k!}+\sin(2\pi i)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\cos\dfrac{k\pi}{2}\cdot\dfrac{\{2\pi (z-i)\}^{k}}{k!}}=
{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sin\left\{\dfrac{k\pi}{2}+2\pi i\right\}\dfrac{\{2\pi (z-i)\}^k}{k!}}.$$

This Taylor series converges on $\mathbb C$. The product gives

$$\tag{1}\dfrac{\sin(2\pi z)}{z(z+i)}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j(z-i)^j$$

with

$$a_j:=\sum_{k=0}^j (-1)^k\left\{\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{(2i)^k}-\dfrac{1}{i^k}\right\}\cdot\left\{\sin\left[\dfrac{(j-k)\pi}{2}+2\pi i\right]\cdot\dfrac{(2\pi)^{j-k}}{(j-k)!}\right\}.$$

The product converges for the smallest radius of convergence which is $\vert z-i\vert\lt1$. But the function

$$\tag{2}\dfrac{\sin(2\pi z)}{z(z+i)}$$

is holomorphic for $\vert z-i\vert\lt2$. Therefore the product converges even for $\vert z-i\vert\lt2$. Now we only have to multiply $(1)$ with $(z-i)^{-1}$.

**Supplement:**

My understanding of the comments is that I multiply two absolutely convergent series, Taylor series in this case, and the product does not converge or it does not converge on the given radius of convergence. Unfortunately I only read German books about analysis. Therefore I will only give German references. But you are free to edit English references.

First we obtain: Theorem $32.6$, Lehrbuch der Analysis, Teil $1$, Harro Heuser [$H1$], $2009$: If the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$ and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k$ are absolutely convergent, their Cauchy product

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (a_0b_k+a_1b_{k-1}+\dots+a_kb_0)=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k\right)$$

is absolutely convergent. Hence within the radius of convergence of two Taylor series we are allowed to take their Cauchy product and that is what I did in $(1)$. Explicitely this is stated for Taylor series in theorem $63.3$, [$H1$]. The latter theorem states that the radius of convergence is the minimum of the the radii of each of the taylor series.

Now complex analysis comes into play. I have established that the series $(1)$ converges for $\vert z-i\vert\lt1$. It is a Taylor series of the function $(2)$. By the identity theorem of Taylor series there exists only one Taylor series for a function, theorem $64.5$, [$H1$] (if there exists one at all). Now complex analysis states: Theorem $187.2$, Lehrbuch der Analysis, Teil $2$, Harro Heuser [$H2$], $2008$: A holomorphic function can be developed to a series $\sum a_k(z-z_0)^k$ around a point $z_0$ in the open neighbourhood $G$ where it is defined. It will converge at least in the largest open disc with center $z_0$ that still lies in $G$. Because this disc can be established to $\vert z-i\vert\lt2$ the series $(1)$ must even converge on this disc!

In my steps of deduction I first stated that the Taylor series $(1)$ holds for $\vert z-i\vert\lt1$. Without this step I may not extend the radius of convergence if I have not proven that it is the taylor series at all. Please keep this in mind. All hinges on the identity theorem of Taylor series.

Comment: The OP already knew all this, read his question carefully.

Comment: You have a problem in $\frac{- i}{z}$ $|z-i|<1$ It is supposed to be valid for $|z-i|<2$

Comment: @topspin That requres to consider three parts (within the inner circle, on the curcumference and within the outer ring), with multiplying of series with $k=-\infty\dots\infty$

Comment: @Reimer Brüchmann That form of solution seems wrong

Answer (score 4):

Let us consider the function
$$f(t) = t^{-1/2}e^{2\pi it^{1/2}} = g_0(h(t))e^{2i\pi t^{1/2}},$$
where
$$g_0(u) = {1\over u},\quad h(t) = t^{1/2},\quad h'(t) = {1\over2}t^{-1/2} = {1\over2u}.$$
Let 
$$f^{(n)}(t) = g_n(h(t))e^{2\pi it}\tag1,$$
then
$$f^{(n)}(t) = \left(g_{n-1}(h(t))e^{2\pi it}\right)'h'(t) = \left(g'_{n-1}+2\pi ig_{n-1}\right)e^{2i\pi t}{1\over2u},$$
$$g_n = {1\over2u}g'_{n-1}+{i\pi\over u}g_{n-1}.\tag2$$
For example,
$$g_1(u) = {1\over2u}\left(-{1\over u^2}\right) + {i\pi\over u^2} = -{1\over2u^3} + {i\pi\over u^2},$$
$$g_2(u) = {1\over2u}\left(-{1\over2u^3} + {i\pi\over u^2}\right)' + {i\pi\over u}\left(-{1\over2u^3} + {i\pi\over u^2}\right)$$
$$ ={1\over2u}\left({3\over2u^4} - {2i\pi\over u^3}\right) + \left(-{i\pi\over2u^4} - {\pi^2\over u^3}\right) = \left({3\over4u^5} - {3\pi i\over2u^4} - {\pi^2\over u^3}\right),$$
$$g_3(u) = {1\over2u}\left({3\over4u^5} - {3\pi i\over2u^4} - {\pi^2\over u^3}\right)' + {i\pi\over u}\left({3\over4u^5} - {3\pi i\over2u^4} - {\pi^2\over u^3}\right)$$
$$ = {1\over2u}\left(-{15\over4u^6} + {6\pi i\over u^5} + {3\pi^2\over u^4}\right) + \left({3i\pi\over4u^6} + {3\pi^2\over2u^5} - {i\pi^3\over u^4}\right)$$
$$ = \left(-{15\over8u^7} + {15\pi i\over4u^6} +{3\pi^2\over u^5} - {\pi^3 i\over u^4}\right),\,\dots$$

One can obtain values of the function 
$$F(t) = {\sin2\pi\sqrt{t\,}\over\sqrt{t\,}} = \Im f(t)\tag3$$ 
and its derivations
$$F^{(n)}(t) = \Im f^{(n)}(t) = \Re g_n(\sqrt{t\,})\sin2\pi\sqrt{t\,} + \Im g_n(\sqrt{t\,})\cos2\pi\sqrt{t\,}\tag4$$
at $t=-1$.

For example,
$$F(-1) = {\sinh(\pm2\pi i)\over\pm  i} = \sinh2\pi,$$
$$F'(-1) = \left.\left(-{1\over2t^{3/2}}\sin{2\pi\sqrt{t\,}} + {\pi\over t}\cos(2\pi\sqrt{t\,})\right)\right|_{t=-1}$$
$$= {\sin({\pm2\pi i})\over\pm2i} - \pi\cos({\pm2\pi i}) = {1\over2}\sinh2\pi - \pi\cosh2\pi,$$
$$F''(-1) = \left.\left(\left({3\over4t^{5/2}} - {\pi^2\over t^{3/2}}\right) \sin(2\pi\sqrt{t\,}) - {3\pi\over2t^2}\cos(2\pi\sqrt{t\,})\right)\right|_{t=-1}$$
$$ = \left({3\over4} + {\pi^2}\right)\sinh(2\pi) - {3\pi\over2}\cosh(2\pi),$$
$$F'''(-1) = \left.\left(\left(-{15\over8t^{7/2}} + {3\pi^2\over t^{5/2}}\right) \sin(2\pi\sqrt{t\,}) + \left({15\pi\over4t^3} - {\pi^3\over t^2}\right)\cos(2\pi\sqrt{t\,})\right)\right|_{t=-1}$$
$$= \left({15\over8} + {3\pi^2}\right)\sinh(2\pi) - \left({15\pi\over4} + \pi^3\right)\cosh(2\pi)\dots$$
The Taylor series in the neighborhood of the point $t=-1$ has the form
$$F(t) = {\sin2\pi\sqrt t\over\sqrt t} = {\sinh2\pi} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n(t+1)^n,\tag5$$
where
$$c_n = {1\over n!}F^{(n)}(-1)\tag6$$
(see also [Wolfram Alfa](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin%20(2%5Cpi%20sqrt%20z)%7D%7Bsqrt%20z%7D%20around%20z%20%3D%20-1)), and the series converges for $t\in\mathbb R.$

Substitution
$$t=z^2$$
gives the series in the form of
$${\sin2\pi z\over z} = {\sinh2\pi} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n(z^2+1)^n,$$
so
$${\sin2\pi z\over z(z^2+1)} = {c_0\over z^2+1} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n(z^2+1)^{n-1}$$
$$ = {1\over2i}{c_0\over(z-i)\left(1+\dfrac{z-i}{2i}\right)} + 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_{n+1}(z-i)^n(z-i+2i)^n$$
$$= c_0(z-i)^{-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n{(z-i)^n\over(2i)^{n+1}}  + \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n\genfrac{(}{)}{0}{0}{n}{k}(2i)^{n-k}(z-i)^{n+k}.$$
Substitution $m=n+k\ $ in the double sum gives
$${\sin2\pi z\over z(z^2+1)}= c_0\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n{(z-i)^{n-1}\over(2i)^{n+1}}  + \sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\left[{m\over2}\right]c_{m-k+1}\genfrac{(}{)}{0}{0}{m-k}{k}(2i)^{m-2k}(z-i)^m$$
$$=  -{c_0i\over2}(z-i)^{-1}+ {c_0\over4}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\left({i\over2}\right)^m(z-i)^m  + \sum_{m=0}^\infty \left(i^m(z-i)^m \sum_{k=0}^\left[{m\over2}\right]i^{-2k}c_{m-k+1}\genfrac{(}{)}{0}{0}{m-k}{k}2^{m-2k}\right)$$
$$=  -{c_0i\over2}(z-i)^{-1}+ \sum_{m=0}^\infty \left(c_02^{-(m+2)} + \sum_{k=0}^\left[{m\over2}\right](-1)^k c_{m-k+1}\genfrac{(}{)}{0}{0}{m-k}{k}2^{m-2k}\right)i^m(z-i)^m$$
$$= -{c_0i\over2}(z-i)^{-1} + {c_0\over4} + c_1  + \left({c_0\over8} + 2c_2\right)i(z-i) - \left({c_0\over16} + 4c_3 - c_2\right)(z-i)^2 + \dots,$$

where
$$c_0 = \sinh2\pi,$$
$$c_1 = {1\over2}\sinh2\pi - \pi\cosh2\pi,$$
$$c_2 = \left({3\over8} + {\pi^2\over2}\right)\sinh2\pi - {3\pi\over4}\cosh2\pi,$$
$$c_3 = \left({5\over16} + {\pi^2\over2}\right)\sinh2\pi - \left({5\pi\over8} + {\pi^3\over6}\right)\cosh2\pi,\,\dots$$

[I.e.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin%20(2%20%5Cpi%20z)%7D%7Bz%20(z%5E2%20%2B1)%7D%20around%20z%20%3Di),
$$\boxed{{\sin2\pi z\over z(z^2+1)} = - {i\sinh2\pi\over2}(z-i)^{-1}+ {3\over4}\sinh2\pi - \pi\cosh2\pi + i\left(\left({7\over8} + \pi^2\right)\sinh2\pi - {3\pi\over2}\cosh2\pi\right)(z-i) + \left(-\left({15\over16} + {3\pi^2\over2}\right)\sinh2\pi + \left({7\pi\over4}+{2\pi^3\over3}\right)\cosh2\pi\right)(z-i)^2 + \dots}$$

Comment: Once again, the OP knew all this, he was looking for a quick way of getting the answer (one that could be used in an exam). Phew!, why don't people read the questions carefully?

Comment: This is only unsuccessful version. The final version will be soon.

Comment: I doubt that there can be a successful version. Not everything is easily computable and not everything has a closed form. The OP hasn't asked this question by mistake, it is clear that he himself had to go through the same effort. *There is no quick solution to the given problem. Attempts to find it are a waste of time.*

Comment: @AlexM. I think that final version is the best thing to do on the exam.

Comment: An expression that is left containing a "big O" term cannot be considered an explicit form of a Taylor series. What is the coefficient of $(z - \Bbb i)^{1987345}$?

Comment: @AlexM. Fixed, thanks.